# How is the vaccination schedule for dogs determined?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

My dog's <sup>**(1)**</sup> vet diary shows a regular vaccination schedule for 3 things:

- Distemper / Hepatitis Parvo / Corona / Leptosspirosis / Parainfluenza (9 in one; injection) — **Once every year.**
- Anti-Rabies (injection) — **Once every year.**
- Deworming (tablets or injection) — **Once in 3 months.**

(I've added some scans below—just to give you a better idea.)

I've read in many places that adult dogs only need to be vaccinated once in 3 years or so, and am worried that I could be over-vaccinating my dog.

There's only one good vet in/around my place (and he has never brought this topic up), which is why I am asking here.

**PS:** Some scans of the labels pasted in my pet's diary...

[image: Vaccination schedule for Distemper / Hepatitis Parvo / Corona / Leptosspirosis / Parainfluenza]

[image: Vaccination schedule for Anti-Rabies]

---

**Footnotes:**

1. He's a Golden Retriever and is 4 years old (born Sept. 12, 2010).

Comment: Where are you reading about the 3 year thing? I've never seen anything that suggests non-annual vax schedules.

Comment: @AshleyNunn I'm betting that's heartworm medicine. Pretty common for dogs I think.

Comment: Some rabies vaccines for cats are rated for 3 years (they're adjuvated, which have problems). I'm not sure what the situation is for dogs. I'm going to edit this question a bit - overvaccination is an opinion.

Comment: @MattS. heartworm preventative is usually given monthly, so I'm not sure what you're thinking of.

Comment: @Zaralynda If heartworm preventative is to be given monthly, doesn't that mean by dog's in trouble? He gets "dewormed" once in 3 months, and I am not sure if it also deals with heartworms. (Should ask my vet next time.)

Comment: Is the deworming medicine on the list? What is it called?

Comment: Heartworm preventative is usually given orally as a tablet. What's the name of the "dewormer" you're using, maybe there's a 3 month version I'm not aware of.

Comment: @MattS. He writes **FP - 12 cc (37 kg)** or recently, **Neomec 1.5 cc (30 kg)** when he does an injection for deworming. I don't know what he prescribed for a tablet, it's been a long time. I'll have to ask him.

Comment: Neomec is ivermectin, and that is used as a heartworm preventative. I'm not familiar with using it every 3 months, but can't find clear direction on the internet.

Comment: @Zaralynda My vet currents prescribes this for deworming: *Drontal Plus*. As my dog weights 30 kg, he gets 3 tablets.

Comment: @MattS. Just got the info (the previous one was old).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the American Animal Hospital Association (AAHA) Canine Vaccination Task Force reviewed recent research on vaccines and how long they remain effective. In 2011 they made [recommendations based on this research](https://www.aahanet.org/PublicDocuments/CanineVaccineGuidelines.pdf).

This table summarizes their recommendations. To make it easier to read, I added a blue star under each core vaccine, and also spelled out some of the abbreviations used for the names and recommendations.

Core vaccines are recommended for all healthy dogs, while non-core vaccines are usually only given if your dog is in a high risk category. You should discuss the pros and cons of non-core vaccines with your vet before administering them.

Here is a short summary of the vaccines that your dog is getting:

- Distemper - Core, immune response lasts for >5 years in healthy dogs,
  dogs should be revaccinated every 3 years.
- Hepatitis Parvo (adenovirus in the chart) - Core, immune response
  lasts for >7 years in healthy dogs, dogs should be revaccinated every
  3 years. There's an option for annual IN if your dog is at risk for
  respiratory infection.
- Corona - not recommended because (in 2011) not believed to be
  effective
- Leptosspirosis - non core. Discuss with your vet.
- Parainfluenza - non core. Discuss with your vet, intranasal may be
  preferable if your dog tolerates it.
- Rabies - Core. There are 1 year and 3 year vaccines available, follow the label on the vaccine your vet uses as to the revaccination interval. In addition, some municipalities do not allow 3 years between rabies vaccination and dogs/cats must be revaccinated annually, no matter which vaccine is used. Check your local laws.

[image]

Comment: I didn't get into worming medications, since they aren't true vaccines. I'm feeling that should be a separate question since this got pretty long...

Comment: Can you please give a separate list for **compulsory** and **optional** vaccines in **tabular form** like this one? http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6935/vaccines-for-cows

Comment: @ParthTrivedi compulsory (required by law) vaccines will vary based on your local laws. The recommendations above are based on recommendations of veterinarians in North America. To get a list of compulsory (required by law) vaccines for your location, I recommend you ask a new question.