# Are there any vaccines that are needed for cows in Gujarat, India?

Tags: medicines, vaccination, farm-animals, cows

I love cows, but I do not know if there are there is any need for cows to have vaccines, whether they're compulsory vaccines or optional vaccines.

If so, which are the schedules for the vaccines?

I would love if someone could give me information for the following table. I ask so I can follow it for my friend's cow and its children. I promise that I will make a printout will give it to all cow-holders of my town. :)

| No | Category | Name of vaccine | Duration Once/Repeat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Compulsory | somename xyz | Every Year |
| 2 | Optional | somename abc | Once |

Are there any vaccines that are needed for cows living in the Gujarat area in India?

Answer (score 2):

India Development Gateway has a [vaccination schedule for dairy cattle](http://www.indg.in/agriculture/animalhusbandary/vaccination-schedule-for-dairy-cattle) on their website, although I cannot personally verify its accuracy.  It is a good idea to ask a local livestock/large animal veterinarian about this, as they will likely know about diseases and conditions specific to your area.